# Find out if threads are still running in threadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have following part of code:

```
protected ExecutorService parallelExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
protected ExecutorService serialExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
List<?> parallelCommands = new ArrayList<?>();
List<?> serialCommands = new ArrayList<?>();
List<Future<Boolean>> results = null;
LocalDateTime timed = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(60);

results = parallelExecutor.invokeAll(parallelCommands);
results.addAll(serialExecutor.invokeAll(serialCommands));
```

Now I would like to check if both executors finish their job within a timeout or not:

```
while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(timed)) {
 \\ here I need to check if meanwhile my threads finished
 \\ if yes, break;}
```

How can I verify if the executors finished their job?

Comment: Call `get` on the futures. Finished ones will return immediately. `get` can also be called with a timeout-setting: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: There may also be a fancy way of doing this with CompleteableFuture ...

Answer (score 0):

JDK documentation:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: This only makes sense if you shutdown the pools.

Comment: I tried to check if executor isTerminated(), but this returns true only if the tasks are finished and followed by shutdown. Seems that pool shutdown is not happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to keep track of each task that finishes. You can decrement and check by modifying tasks added to your task list or by using a `CompletableFuture`.

```
List<Callable<?>> tasks = ...
ExecutorService executor = ...

// Might want to add the size of your other task list as well
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(tasks.size());

for (Callable<?> callable : tasks) {
    results.add(executor.submit(new Callable() {
        callable.call();
        int value = counter.decrementAndGet();

        if (value == 0) {
            synchronized (this) {
                OuterClass.this.notify();
            }
        }
    });
}
long timed = System.currentTimeMillis();

synchronized (this) {
    long timeLeft;

    // Or however many millis your timeout is
    while ((timeLeft = 60_000 - System.currentTimeMillis() - timed) > 0) {
        this.wait(timeLeft);
    }
}
```

What you want to do is wait until you run out of time on your main thread, while your tasks are executed by the executor. If a task finishes and it realizes that there are no tasks that haven't finished, it tells the waiting thread to continue. I use `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()` because no other threads should be waiting for this object except the main thread, but if you do have other threads, use the latter option.